# (AWS) Extract the EBS volume from an AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, amazon-ami

An Amazon Machine Image contains an EBS volume. Is there a way to get the EBS volume out of the AMI without booting the AMI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the EBS volume out of the AMI without booting
>   the AMI?

Did you create the AMI from one of your instances? If false then no.

Does the AMI have licensing requirements (e.g. Windows or RedHat)? The licensing will not follow with the new volume meaning it won't boot.

If you created the AMI, then you will also have a snapshot that the AMI references. You can then create a volume from the snapshot.

Otherwise you will need to launch an instance from the AMI.

Comment: It seems like if you have permission to launch an AMI, you should also have permission to create volumes from its associated snapshots, even if you didn't create it, since you have to grant this too when sharing an AMI... but I may be missing a detail that makes this impossible.

Comment: yes, apparently when you select the menu to create an image (AMI) for a VM, it automatically creates a snapshot.

Answer (score 2):

If you find the snapshot associated with the AMI, yes you can treat it like any EBS volume snapshot.